# How can I avoid multiple function implementations with GADTs?

Tags: haskell, gadt

First of all, here is a minimum example of my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- package "url"
import Network.URL (exportURL, URL(..), URLType(..))

data MyURL a where
    GalleryURL :: URL -> MyURL URL
    PictureURL :: URL -> MyURL URL

url = URL { url_type = PathRelative, 
            url_path = "www.google.com", 
            url_params = []}

galleryURL = GalleryURL url

myExportURL :: MyURL a -> String
myExportURL (GalleryURL a) = exportURL a
myExportURL (PictureURL a) = exportURL a

main = print $ myExportURL galleryURL
```

I use GADTs to avoid mixing different kinds of URLs. The `myExportURL` function is the same for all kinds of URLs. Is there a way to use something like this:

```
myExportURL (_ a) = exportURL a
```

instead of repeating it for every subtype (what is the correct term?) of the GADT?

Any other comments on the code or the problem i am trying to solve are also welcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct term is "for every constructor".

Your GADT look suspicious as all your constructors construct the same `MyURL URL` type. If it's all you want then you don't need GADTs in the first place and can use plain ADTs:

```
data MyURL = GalleryURL URL | PictureURL URL
```

To have shorter `myExportUrl` there are different options. One is to refactor the type:

```
data URLKind = GalleryURL | PictureURL
data MyURL = MyURL { myUrlKind :: URLKind, myExportURL :: URL }
```

This way you can still use "short" form of construction, e.g. `MyURL PictureURL foo`. And also you can use `myExportURL` function generated for you by Haskell.

GADTs are only necessary in advanced cases so if your example does not demonstrate fully why you need GADTs then let us now.

Comment: No, there is no reason to use GADTs other than I just learned about them and wanted to do something with it. As Cirdec pointed out, it doesn't even solve my problem. At least I know a little bit more about GADTs now (and when to not use them).

Comment: I'm doing a very similar design with a nanomsg client right now that uses GADTs to constrain network addresses. It's very prototype-level at this point but you can see that GADTs constrain URLs to represent either Inbound or Outbound connections only--it's not possible to switch. https://github.com/tel/hs-nanomsg/blob/master/src/Network/Nanomsg/C/Address.hs#L102

Answer (score 8):

Your MyURL type doesn't prevent you from mixing gallery and picture URLs. Both a GalleryURL and a PictureURL have the same type, `MyURL URL`. Try something like this instead:

```
data Gallery = Gallery

data Picture = Picture

data MyURL a where
    MyURL :: a -> URL -> MyURL a
```

Then you can write the remainder of your code like you imagined:

```
url = URL { url_type = PathRelative, 
            url_path = "www.google.com", 
            url_params = []}

galleryURL = MyURL Gallery url

myExportURL :: MyURL a -> String
myExportURL (MyURL _ a) = exportURL a

main = print $ myExportURL galleryURL
```

You don't need a GADT when all of the constructors work for all of the types, and you don't really need constructors for the Gallery and Picture types, so you could write these parts as:

```
data Gallery -- requires the empty type extension
data Picture
data MyURL a = MyURL URL

galleryURL :: MyURL Gallery
galleryURL = MyURL url

myExportURL :: MyURL a -> String
myExportURL (MyURL a) = exportURL a
```

Comment: THis is an example of using "phantom types" in case you want to read up more on it.

Comment: @user5402 Is it really a phantom type since there is a value of type `a` in the GADT? The phantom type would be `MyUrl :: URL -> MyURL a`

Comment: I was referring to you last suggestion. In the declaration `data MyURL a = MyURL URL`, `a` is a phantom since it doesn't appear on the RHS.

Comment: @user5402 Apologizes, I missed the last example, I thought you meant the top code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested modifying the data structure, here is a different approach using pattern synonyms:

```
{-# Language GADTs, PatternSynonyms, ViewPatterns, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Kind

data MyURL a where
  GalleryURL :: URL -> MyURL URL
  PictureURL :: URL -> MyURL URL

url :: MyURL a -> URL
url (GalleryURL u) = u   --  Proof that: URL ~ a
url (PictureURL u) = u   --  Proof that: URL ~ a

-- Works on ‘MyURL a’ for any ‘a’
pattern Url :: URL -> MyURL a 
pattern Url u <- (url -> u)
```

Should another constructor be added that does not contain a `URL` we must add a failure case for `url`

```
data MyURL a where
  GalleryURL :: URL -> MyURL URL
  PictureURL :: URL -> MyURL URL
  I          :: Int -> MyURL Int

url :: MyURL a -> Maybe URL
url (GalleryURL u) = Just u    --  Proof that: URL ~ a
url (PictureURL u) = Just u    --  Proof that: URL ~ a
url (I i)          = Nothing   --  Proof that: Int ~ a

pattern Url :: URL -> MyURL a 
pattern Url u <- (url -> Just u)

showMyURL :: MyURL a -> String
showMyURL (Url u) = show u
showMyURL (I   i) = show i   --  Proof that: Int ~ a
```

Yet! — Let's say that we want an evaluation function that returns an `a` when given `MyURL a` — this works as intended

```
eval :: MyURL a -> a
eval (GalleryURL url) = url   --  Proof that: URL ~ a
eval (PictureURL url) = url   --  Proof that: URL ~ a
eval (I int)          = int   --  Proof that: Int ~ a
```

but our new `Url` pattern synonym fails!

```
eval :: MyURL a -> a
eval (Url url) = url
```

We get *no new information* about `a` when we pattern match on the pattern synonym

```
pattern Url :: URL -> MyURL a
```

the connection between `a` and `URL` has been severed. We import [Data.Type.Equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html) and add a proof `Refl :: a :~: URL` that `a` equals `URL`:

```
-- Gets ‘URL’ from a ‘MyURL URL’
--
-- ‘Refl’ is our proof that the input is ‘MyURL URL’ 
url :: MyURL a -> Maybe (a :~: URL, a)
url (GalleryURL url) = Just (Refl, url)
url (PictureURL url) = Just (Refl, url)
url (I          int) = Nothing
```

Then we say that `Url _` provides a proof that `a ~ URL` when matched against,

```
pattern Url :: () => a ~ URL => a -> MyURL a
pattern Url url <- (Url -> (Refl, url))
```

and the `URL` can again be retrieved with a single pattern

```
eval :: MyURL a -> a
eval (Url url) = url   --  Proof that: URL ~ a
eval (I   int) = int   --  Proof that: Int ~ a
```